# get data as pfiles within kernel module code in solaris

Tags: c, kernel, solaris

When I execute on solaris 11.0:

```
pfiles /proc/PROCESSID
```

The result is process information, a small chunk of output is what interest me:

```
 4: S_IFSOCK mode:0666 dev:543,0 ino:46228 uid:0 gid:0 size:0
  O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK
    SOCK_STREAM
    SO_REUSEADDR,SO_KEEPALIVE,SO_SNDBUF(49152),SO_RCVBUF(128480)
    sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.10.50.28  port: 22
    peername: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.16.6.150  port: 55504
```

The process I pfiles /proc/PROCESSID is the sshd session itself.

**My question is given a process id, how can i get this (pfiles) information from within a kernel code ?**

When looking in *struct proc* i could not find something that give me this data.

Is there a pointer to struct that hold all open files occupied by the process on the proccess' proc?

I also executed *truss pfiles /proc/PROCESSID* but could not find the exact call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [look in `/usr/include/sys/user.h`](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/sys/user.h#250) you'll see the open file information can be found in the `p_user.u_finfo` structure of the current process.

Walking that structure is not trivial.  Just [look at what the `proc` filesystem code has to do to look up the attributes of just one open file descriptor](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/fs/proc/prvnops.c#4011).  There's lots of locking needed - you can't simply walk the data structures while things are running.

And, the following is beyond the scope of the question, but it's important...

For what it's worth, what you're doing can't work.  It's fundamentally flawed - technically and legally.

What you're trying to do - track users who share a user account - is worthless anyway.  You will never be able to prove that just because a certain login session executed some code that the code was executed because the user logged into that session purposely ran that code.  **Because any of the users with access to that account can modify the environment of the shared account such that malware is run by someone else**.  And they can make it look just like a typed-in command.

[Shared credentials and accounts violate nonrepudiation.](https://www.google.com/search?q=nonrepudiation)  That's your insurmountable legal flaw in using any data your custom kernel tracking may produce - even if you manage to produce a system that's foolproof, which isn't likely.

If I'm logged into a shared account, you can **never** prove that the code I ran was run intentionally.

Well, that's not entirely true - if you have *perfect* auditing where you can trace every thing a user does down to the bytes modified on disk, you can.  And "perfect" in this case means those users have no access whatsoever to change any part of the auditing system.

But if you already have perfect auditing in place, you don't need to write kernel modules to try and implement it.

Of course, it's impossible to prove you have perfect auditing in place because you can't prove that you don't have holes in it.

See the problem?

We're right back to "You **CAN'T** prove I did it intentionally."

You'd be much better off just using the OS-provided auditing services.  Whatever you come up with isn't going to be useful in proving "who did it" for any intelligent bad actor - like someone who figures out a way to insert malicious code into another user's session.  And the OS auditing will be sufficient to catch anyone who has no clue in how to cover their tracks.

But you won't be able to provably catch any bad actor who knows what he's doing when shared accounts are involved.  And if you can't prove it, you might not even be able to do anything at all to someone you suspect.  Because someone who really knows what they're doing will be able to pin the apparent blame on someone who's innocent - if they can't hide or destroy the evidence of the bad act[s] in the first place.

**What are you going to do if you find the shared `.profile` file has a line in it that after a certain date emails sensitive data to a throwaway email account, but only when the login comes from a certain IP address?**

Any one of the users who share that one account could have put it in there.

No auditing system in the world can solve that problem unless it's perfect *and* tracks every file change.

If the data you're trying to protect is important, whoever is tasking you to solve the problem by writing custom kernel modules needs to grow a brain and solve the real problem - shared user accounts.  Get rid of them.

There's a reason why every security guide says not to use shared accounts, and every security audit I've ever seen will fail anyone using shared accounts.